# Reverse a git fetch

Tags: git, git-fetch

I have a thorough understanding of git, and the difference between pull, fetch, and merge.  I have a remote that I track, fetch, and merge with occasionally, let say it's origin/master.  What I'm looking to do is reverse the behavior of a 'git fetch'.  It sounds goofy, but I want to un-update where my remote tracking branch points, to an older state, the state right before the last fetch.  Is this possible?

For example, lets say this is my workflow...

```
git show origin/master # shows commit abc123

git fetch              # yay i got something!

git show origin/master # shows commit def456
```

**mystery command goes here so that...**

```
git show origin/master # shows commit abc123
```

It's kind of a weird thing to want, but I have a crontab that watches a git repo to detect when there's something to fetch, and I'm having issues debugging the script that performs some actions based on this behavior.  Instead of waiting for origin/master to change, I'd like to change it myself so I can debug my script!

Comment: It's not that weird ... I just fetched, and got a bunch of changes that I don't want and I want to do the same thing ... have my remote-tracking branch point to an older version of that repo (as if I had not fetched).  I know those changes are not in my working directory ... I don't even want them on my remote-tracking branch.  Thank you for asking this question and getting an answer in time for me to be able to refer to it  : -)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You want

> `git update-ref refs/remotes/origin/master refs/remotes/origin/master@{1}`

`update-ref` wants the full spell on the ref it's updating because it's (much) lower level than the commands that respect ref-naming conventions.

Comment: Awesome, that was exactly what I was looking for! One can say that this command does exactly "undo fetch". 
But I wonder what does {1} mean in the command? I wanted to undo fetch with 30+ new commits and {3} worked for me, not "30"

Comment: The @{} syntax is documented here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#_git_reflog . In short, `@{n}` means "n'th entry from reflog". `git log -g origin/master` shows the reflog of origin/master, with `@{n}` annotations. So `@{1}` means "before last fetch", assuming you run it right after a fetch.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a "reverse a git fetch" answer, but it seems your *actual* problem is how to programmatically "watch a repo for changes" without necessarily altering your repository in any way.

For this, you can use `git fetch --dry-run`. A dry run will not cause any changes to your repository, but if there are changes in the remote, then it will have some basic terminal output; if there are no changes there will not be any output. If you want to have this running as an automated script instead of a manual check, it should be relatively straightforward to create a simple bash script that tests `git fetch --dry-run` for output.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there's an actual git command to do it, and this is a big hackish, but...

```
echo $OLD_COMMIT > .git/refs/remotes/origin/master
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

I hope this time I got what you want and I think it's this:

```
git rebase origin/master --onto origin/master^
```